# How to use this function?

Tags: php, function, coordinates

Hi i have the following function to calculate distance between to coordinates:

```
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)
{
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
$lat1 *= $pi80;
$lng1 *= $pi80;
$lat2 *= $pi80;
$lng2 *= $pi80;

$r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
$dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
$dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
$a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
$km = $r * $c;

return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

How can i use this function? I simply put this before the function, and thought $km will be the outcome. This doesn't work.

```
$lat1 = $info[lat];
$lng1 = $info[lng];
$lat2 = $latpost;
$lng2 = $lngpost;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fundamental programming basics.

Comment: Is you've ever written PHP code you've possibly called functions before. `distance()` doesn't have anything fancy or special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the function:

```
$distance = distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true);
```

Comment: +1 simplicity is always the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Call it like this

```
$dist = distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, true);
```

OR

```
$dist = distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, false);
```

OR you can omit the last parameter (Which will be the same as calling it with true):

```
$dist = distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2);
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use it like you write it

```
$myresult = distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true);
echo $myresult;
```

and the function is counting the arc tangent from an object around the globe..

i think theres nothing more to say..